# What is the best way to enable deep linking in nativescript app

Tags: android, nativescript

i'm trying to use deep linking to allow my nativescript app open when a link is clicked.

I've checked the examples online but still the link opens on my browser when i click it on whatsapp
This is my AndroidManiest.xml file exactly how it is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.myskog.xyz" />
                <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How do i fix this please

Comment: Did you try a clean build? Can you confirm the URL you are trying to launch from WhatsApp?

Comment: @Manoj Thanks, i just ran a clean build, still doesn't work, its opening in broswer. the url i'm launching is http://www.myskog.xyz/skog

Comment: Did you remove LAUNCHER from your manifest, which must have removed app icon form your dashboard?

Comment: @Manoj i have updated the question to show exactly what is on my AndroidManifest please check

Comment: @Manoj just to be clear, which AndroidManifest am i to edit, the one in App_resources of the one in platforms folder?

Comment: @Manoj thanks, i have fixed it, i was supposed to edit the Manifest file in platforms folder also

Comment: You are suppose to edit only the manifest in the app resources. The one in the platforms folder is auto generated and expected to be auto updated by the changes you make. I'm not sure what you understood by clean build, it means cleaning your platform folder and rebuild to ensure new changes are picked up.

Comment: @Manoj i thought so too, for the clean build, i ran `tns build android --clean` and it didn't work until i manually edited it